# Create dynamic edge with JGraphX

Tags: java

I'm doing an activity diagram editor using JGraphX​​. User should do this steps to create an edge between two nodes (vertex):

1. he clicks a button (to say that 'I will now create an edge'), then
2. click on the chosen source node,
3. drag with the mouse,
4. release the mouse when it reaches the second node to bind.

I know it is done with MouseClicked, and MouseDragged MouseReleased but I have not found the correct solution.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

`BasicGraphEditor` example, that is bundled with JGraphX under `examples` package, demonstrates implementation of such a use case. See `mxConnectionHandler` API reference for more details.